# SoftQuad DESC or font file binary

Tags: image, format, png, binaryfiles

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950622/what-is-softquad-desc) but it doesn't helped me. I am solving a challenge where I have two files, first one was .png which gave me upper half part of an image, second file is **SoftQuad DESC or font file binary** I am sure that this file should somehow convert into .png file to complete the image. I googled and got hint about magic bytes but I am unable to match the bytes.

These are the first two rows of output of xxd command

```
00000000: aaaa a6bb 67bb bf18 dd94 15e6 252c 0a2f  ....g.......%,./
00000010: fe14 d943 e8b5 6ad5 2264 1632 646e debc  ...C..j."d.2dn..
```

These are the last two rows of output of xxd command

```
00001c10: 7a05 7f4c 3600 0000 0049 454e 44ae 4260  z..L6....IEND.B`
00001c20: 82 
                                 .
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. Also attach your images.

Comment: @ZF007 output of xxd is very big, so I just posted upper and lower two lines to just identify the magic bytes and know the format

Comment: perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HoTMetaL) and [this](https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-495/file/magdir/softquad) get you on the road. Corel got SoftQuad in its company portfolio... and apple got something with referals to bitmaps or something.

Comment: @ZF007 your second link was my doubt, you can see that none of the byte order in the link match with the output which I uploaded.

Comment: Since we got moved to jpeg, tiff, png, etc..why bother at all? Digging in the [internet archieves](https://web.archive.org/web/*/SoftQuad)... shows **7,055** results. Nice quest you're on but this is my busstop here... hope you find the complete digital raptor skeleton. Did my upvote for originality and totally non-wiki question ;-)

Comment: @usr2564301 I gave link above, is Dropbox ok?

Comment: IEND is the PNG end-of-file marker (chunk). Have you tried just concatenating the two files, and see if that's the full PNG?

Comment: @haraldK how to do that?

Comment: @Debian Sorry about my initial reply (I'm on Windows at work). I did of course mean [`cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347278/how-can-i-copy-several-binary-files-into-one-file-on-a-linux-system). ;-)

Comment: @haraldK Thanks dude, it worked I had first file as png so I just used cat file1.png file2 > target. So it just concated both files and final image formed is .png