# Bash equivalent of "copy /b" from powershell

Tags: bash, powershell

In powershell,

```
copy /b file1.o+file2.o file.bin
```

This command combines two binary files(file1.o, file2.o) and write that to another binary file. (file.bin)

Is there bash equivalent of this command?

Is there option for this in `cp` command?
Or should I use another tool to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I copy several binary files into one file on a Linux system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347278/how-can-i-copy-several-binary-files-into-one-file-on-a-linux-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cat` command with redirection, it works with binaries :

```sh
cat file1.o file2.o > file.bin
```