# Unable to Copy data from POD to local using kubectl cp command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I need to copy dump data from pod to local. Below the commands I am trying but I am getting error: `unexpected EOF`

```
kubectl cp device-database-79fc964c8-q7ncc:tmp /Users/raja
error: unexpected EOF

or

kubectl cp device-database-79fc964c8-q7ncc:tmp/plsql_data/prod.dump /Users/raja/prod.dump
error: unexpected EOF
```

kubectl version

```
kubectl version --client
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:31:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
```

Can anyone help how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Kubernetes, when trying to `cp` big files. I assume that's your case. See: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60140

Comment: Could you move your db dump to a separate directory and then try to copy the entire directory ? This may look like this: `kubectl cp device-database-79fc964c8-q7ncc:tmp/plsql_data/directory_containing_prod_dump /Users/raja/new_local_dir_containing_db_dump`. According to [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60140#issuecomment-836448850) it may help.

Comment: The solution by mario worked. It should be a top-level answer.

Comment: Copying the entire directory worked for me. Thanks @mario

Comment: @BageshwarPratapNarain , I'm glad to hear that my solution helped you. Let me post it as an answer then.

Comment: @İbrahimULUDAĞ, glad to hear that my soluiton helped you. I'm posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using a "cat" command, rather than "cp" worked for me -- but only after 3 attempts.

The "cp" command failed over and over to get the whole file.

This "cat" style command did better each time.

So try this and see if your odds improve!

```
kubectl exec -i [pod name] -c [container name] -- cat [path to file] > [output file]
```

Comment: same issue happened to me today. it was working fine before. tysm

Comment: This issue appears to be actively under investigation by the developers as kubernetes Issue #60140.

Comment: @Gaurav not true - I just used the above to download binary files with no problem

Comment: Better way would to use tar instead of cat, as suggested here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#copy-files-and-directories-to-and-from-containers

Comment: This should definitely not be the accepted solution. You risk data loss here for some reason. Probably it's related to @Gaurav comment. My file was 71MB on remote and 68MB on my local machine. Checksums also obviously didn't match. I haven't got any error message though.

Comment: @Gaurav that is a false statement about `cat` - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10347303/1218512)

Comment: You need `tar` to be installed in a pod container to work with `kubectl cp`. That's why only `cat` worked in your case.

Comment: Beware that this `cat` trick may break binary files. I did that with a Java heap dump and the file was modified during the transfer. The `md5sum` of the file on the pod didn't match the `md5sum` of the file I got locally.

Answer (score 71):

For newer versions of kubectl, adding a retries=-1 flag may resolve the issue:

```
kubectl cp --retries=-1 pod-www-xxx-yyy-zzz:/path/to/remote/dir ~/local/dir
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, at least as from kubectl 1.23. However, above syntax is not correct. Should be a flag `--retries=n`, with n a negative number to retry/resume forever or a positive number to indicate the number of retries.

So `kubectl cp --retries=10 pod-www-xxx-yyy-zzz:/path/to/remote/dir_or_file ~/local/dir_or_file`

Comment: Thanks @janFrederik - corrected syntax as per your comment.

Comment: Tried this today, but on 2 subsequent attempts the respective resulting files were different. It appears that data is "stitched" wrongly each time

Answer (score 8):

Could you **move your db dump to a separate directory** and then try to **copy the entire directory** ?

This may look like this:

```
kubectl cp device-database-79fc964c8-q7ncc:tmp/plsql_data/directory_containing_prod_dump /Users/raja/new_local_dir_containing_db_dump
```

According to  [this comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60140#issuecomment-836448850)  it may help.

It was also confirmed in comments by [Bageshwar Pratap Narain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376640/bageshwar-pratap-narain) and [İbrahim ULUDAĞ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447572/%C4%B0brahim-uluda%C4%9E) that this solution worked for them.

Comment: For me, simply copy the file to `/tmp/` (before copying from pod to local machine) also worked, I'm in a windows machine.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Still consistently receiving `error: unexpected EOF` for a 5MB logfile in the folder, while a 31MB logfile copies nicely without error.

Comment: Same workaround did it for me with openshift-cli

Answer (score 5):

My kubectl version (1.22) throws an error using `retries`:

```
Error: unknown flag: --retries
```

But, if you look at `kubectl options`, you'll find `--request-timeout='0'`

So, I did `kubectl cp --request-timeout=3m ...` and it worked for a 8MB file.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround that works for me:

```
kubectl exec pod_name -- bash -c "tar cf - /remote/path; sleep 10" | tar xf - -C /local/path
```

The `sleep 10` step is intended to prevent premature teardown, which seemed to be the problem in my case.

It's clearly a hacky workaround to mitigate a race condition in the teardown. But it helps me copy the file over, so I'll take it.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. I've created the following ticket for kubectl, maybe somebody can find out where the issue is: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1361

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue today after doing some research and found that the connection is getting timed out before downloading the complete file suggest you use

```
--retries=10
```

The complete command will be

```
kubectl  cp --retries=10 <Name of namespace>/<pod-name>:<Path of file in pod> <Path of file in local>
```

For eg.

```
kubectl  cp --retries=10 cf/abc-service-58bf-xj8wr:/tmp/app.hprof /tmp/test_heap.hprof
```

Answer (score 1):

As per kubectl documentation, the files and directories should be in .tar extension for kubectl cp to work, otherwise it will fail.

```
    kubectl cp --help

Copy files and directories to and from containers.

Examples:
  # !!!Important Note!!!
  # Requires that the 'tar' binary is present in your container
  # image.  If 'tar' is not present, 'kubectl cp' will fail.
  #
  # For advanced use cases, such as symlinks, wildcard expansion or
  # file mode preservation consider using 'kubectl exec'.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case. Copying folder didn't helped. Instead tar.gz helps

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30619409)

Answer (score 0):

I removed '[' symbols for my all file names and it worked for me